# Reading Items inside of an array in an array C++

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I have a very quick question...

I'm using nlohmann's json library.

My issue is that when I go to print a element, the program stops responding.

My json file

```
{
  "Consoleprinting": false,
  "Input" : [{"Code" : [{"Name": "EC", "Keybind": "VK_NUMPAD1"}] }]
}
```

What I have tried.

```
nlohmann::json jsonData = nlohmann::json::parse(i_Read);

std::cout << jsonData << std::endl;

for (auto& array : jsonData["Input"]) {
    std::cout << array["Code"] << std::endl;
}
```

^ This works but it prints out

```
[{"Name": "EC", "Keybind": "VK_NUMPAD1"}]
```

How can I get this it print out just the name?

Comment: `array["Code"][0]["Name"]`?

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Good, but please don't edit the question to show the answer. Instead, post an answer.

Comment: Sorry! I'm new to using stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array["Code"]` is an array containing a single collection of key-value pairs, so you need to write:

```
std::cout << array["Code"][0]["Name"] << std::endl;
```

Comment: I get it now! Due to the array not being set back to 0 it still thinks its at the other value correct?

Comment: No, you're just not printing the right thing. You need to access the elements you want, that's all.